# Common principles and ideas of cryptography

Tags: standards

There are several common principles and ideas in modern cryptography, which are generally accepted and taken into account. An example may be [Kerckhoffs's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle):

1. The system must be practically, if not mathematically, indecipherable;
2. It should not require secrecy, and it should not be a problem if it falls into enemy hands;
3. It must be possible to communicate and remember the key without using written notes, and correspondents must be able to change or modify it at will;
4. It must be applicable to telegraph communications;
5. It must be portable, and should not require several persons to handle or operate;
6. Lastly, given the circumstances in which it is to be used, the system must be easy to use and should not be stressful to use or require its users to know and comply with a long list of rules.

Another example are the principles for modern cryptography from Lindell and Katz: Exact definition, precise assumption and proof of security.

**My question:**
Are there any other principles or important ideas and statements?

Comment: Balancing bandwidth-security-performance would definitely be one, although I currently have no idea to articulate it.

Comment: I'd complete 6 with 6b which would capture some "misuse-resiliency": all things being equal, we'd prefer if security doesn't *completely* break down if e.g. the user doesn't generate an IV at random, reuses an IV, reuses passwords...

Comment: Modern cryptography (as a continuation of cryptology) contains a lot more than ciphers. What you mention seems to focus on ciphers only, and to be honest, I think that such a narrowing of scope is required. For instance, digital elections are also part of cryptography but they will have an entirely different scope and "principles  and ideas" associated with it.